# Error: Property 'driverClassName' must not be empty

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'driverClassName' must not be empty

It works when I remove @Profile

```
@Profile("web")
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.demo.bank")
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

}
```

for the reference i adding test case snippet.

> ```
> @WebAppConfiguration
> @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
> @ContextConfiguration(classes = { AppConfig.class })
> public class InsertTestCase {
>   @Mock
>   CommonService commonService;
>
>   @InjectMocks
>   HomeController homeController;
>
>   @Autowired
>   WebApplicationContext wac;
>
>   MockMvc mockMvc;
>
>   @Before
>   public void init() {
>       MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
>   }
>
>   @Test
>   public void testRoot() {
>       try {
>           this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(homeController).build();
>           MvcResult mvcResult = this.mockMvc.perform(get("/")).andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn();
>           logger.info("Response:-\t" + mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString());
>       } catch (Exception e) {
>           e.printStackTrace();
>       }
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What exactly the problem here?

Comment: when i am testing from browser it is working fine but from test case it is getting failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Did you added active profile in application.properties or yml file. ?
Or passing by command line?*

**If not pass like below:**

> spring.profiles.active=web

Or (from command)

> --spring.profiles.active=web

Comment: yeah, i have added in WebInitializer class and started working but if remove _@ActiveProfile and _@profile, 
test case is getting failed, i have searched a lot but no luck...